# $f,g$ be irr poly of degree $m$ and $n$. Show that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in some extension of $F$, then $g$ is ireducible in $F(\alpha)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Question: let $f,g\in F[x]$ be irreducible polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$, respectively, for $(m,n)=1$.  Show that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in some extension of $F$, then $g$ is ireducible in $F(\alpha)[x]$.

Thoughts: First, suppose $\beta$ is a root of $g$ in some extension of $F$.  First, we claim that $\beta\notin F(\alpha)$.  To show this, we can assume that $\beta\in F(\alpha)$.  Then, $F\subseteq F(\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha)$, thus $[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\beta)][F(\beta):F]\implies m=[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]n\implies n|m$, which is a contradiction as $m$ and $n$ are coprime.  Now, back to the proof of the question.  We want to show that $g(x)$ is irreducible in $F(\alpha)[x]$.  Suppose, by contradiction, that $g(x)$ is reducible in $F(\alpha)[x]$.  Then, we can write $g(x)$ as a product of irreducible factors, $g_1\cdots g_k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, where the $g_i$'s are in $F(\alpha)[x]$, and at least one of the $g_i$'s equal $0$ when evaluated at $\beta$.  Suppose $g_1(\beta)=0$.  Then $[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)]=deg(g_1)<n$... but I can't seem to get to a contradiction to show the result.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta$ be a root of $g$.  It is not necessarily the case that $F(\beta)$ is contained in $F(\alpha)$, so we should instead look at the extension $F(\alpha, \beta)$ of $F$, which contains both $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$.  We can write the degree of $F(\alpha,\beta)$ over $F$ in two ways:

$$ [F(\alpha,\beta) : F(\alpha)][F(\alpha) : F] = [F(\alpha, \beta) : F(\beta)][F(\beta) : F]$$

or in other words,

$$ m[F(\alpha,\beta) : F(\alpha)] = n[F(\alpha,\beta) : F(\beta)]$$

Clearly, $n$ divides the product of $m$ (to which it is relatively prime) and $[F(\alpha,\beta) : F(\alpha)]$.  If $g$, whose degree is $n$, is not irreducible over $F(\alpha)$, then the extension $[F(\alpha,\beta) : F(\alpha)]$ must be an integer which is strictly less than $n$.  See if you can get a contradiction from here.

Comment: Hi!  I believe what you typed is what I have above... and where you leave off is where I left off...  That is my issue: once I get that $[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)]<n$, I can't seem to conjur up a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: if $n$ divides a product $AB$, and is relatively prime to $A$, then it must divide $B$.

Comment: Ah, wow, so is it literally since $n$ divides $m[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)]$, and as $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then $n$ divides $[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)]$, which is strictly less than $n$.  viola.

Comment: Cello $\space $